# Is it on-topic to post a question that may be related to system configuration?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have encountered a problem using R and posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702984/inconsistent-predictions-from-gbm-predict)

Following the comments there, where no one was able to reproduce the problem, I suspect that it has to do with my system configuration. I do not have another system to test on, but I have done a completely fresh install of R on the same system, and I still have the problem, whereas if I run the exact same 7 lines of code on https://rdrr.io/snippets/ there is no problem - it runs as expected.

Is it on-topic to post about this on SO - or should I post it on another of SEs sites ?

Comment: Don't jump the gun, you are only guessing that it is system config issue.  It could just as easily be a bug in the specific version of the library you use.  Some users report seeing problems as well, you'll have to wait until somebody can find the time to diagnose it.

Comment: Fyi, the standard way to cover all bases related to R configuration is to show `sessionInfo()` per https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269

Answer (score 18):

Your question is *fine*.

You've demonstrated what we're looking for here:

- You've got code such that someone *might* be able to reproduce the issue you have.
- You've showcased that you've made an attempt at tracking the issue down yourself, too.
- You're engaged and keeping the question up-to-date.

If nothing else, your question demonstrates that there may be a discrepancy between either the version of this software you run locally and the version running on a hosted site.  Isolating that discrepancy is necessary here, but you're still well on your way to having a good question thus far.

Comment: Thank you. after further testing I have found that the problem only occurs with the latest version of the `gbm` package. The previous version works as expected. I was going to post this as an answer to my own question, and then re-post a new question specifically about the discrepancy between package versions - is that OK ?

Comment: Sure - that's fantastic.  You've discovered the problem, are going to share your findings with others, and then ask a related question about the discrepancy.  You couldn't have done it any cleaner than this.

Comment: Thanks again. I have answered with a link to the new post.

Answer (score 3):

Your question should try to provide a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is, a brief and reproducible example.

If you require a certain R version to be installed in a certain way on a certain Linux distro for others to reproduce this, it will become difficult for others to help you. But that doesn't make it off-topic per definition. It just makes it harder to get answers.

Problems that are not reproducible can get closed as either lacking an MCVE or as not reproducible. But generally if you tell us that you can consistently reproduce it on your system, and provide enough details for us to replicate your setup, that should not be applicable, and your question should be on-topic.

Telling us you can't replicate it under certain systems/setups does help, because it will make it clear it's configuration-dependent and people being unable to reproduce it will be less likely to see it as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly on-topic to post such a question and as far as I can see, nobody has argued that the [particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702984/inconsistent-predictions-from-gbm-predict) was off-topic.

Now, given that question and the nice answer you provided by yourself after investigating in depth (possibly with a litte help from some of us in the comments), plus a [relevant issue](https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm/issues/28) just opened @ Github (since it was apparent by then that the puzzling behavior is due to a bug), arguably your [second follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706456/inconsistent-predictions-from-gbm-predict-2-1-4-vs-2-1-3) question may be considered off-topic (I, for one, consider it so): I cannot think of any other answer in that second question ("What is the best way to proceed here?") other than "use a previous version and consider opening an issue @ Github", which you have already done yourself in the way...

A nice exercise here would be to ask yourself the question: given the discovery of the bug and the relevant report at Github, is there any *programming* issue left? And what could be a good answer in this second question of yours - again, beyond downgrading to a previous version & open a Github issue, which have been already offered as answers...

As I have already commented, however, I admit that we may be in some gray zone here; and that's why we have such a voting system in place in order to *collectively* decide if a question is off-topic or no...